# Bootstrap 3 & Font Awesome clipping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, font-awesome

I have created a quick & dirty simple website with Bootstrap 3 & Fontawesome .  Everything looks good except when on mobile (phone) and the phone is in landscape (rotated).  I am seeing a weird right hand clipping (see below) on two of the four Font Awesome Icons.  I have tested it on several different browsers / mobile phones, with all the same results.

[image: vertical screen shot]

correct

[image: horizontal screen shot]

incorrect - with clipping

```
<div class="row rowpad">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="/menu/"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span> <h5>Menu</h5></a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="/bar/"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-glass fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span> <h5>Bar Menu</h5></a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="/social/"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span> <h5>Social</h5></a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="/where/"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span> <h5>Directions</h5></a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?  Anything I am over looking?  Thanks.

[live website](http://www.pasticheme.com/)

Comment: I don't have a mobile device here to test, but both firefox and chrome rendered it normaly.

Comment: Looks fine on an iPhone 4S with mobile Safari (iOS 7) and a Huawei Prism II with stock Android (4.1) browser. (Well, technically the "cards" aren't quite horizontally centered, but there's no clipping like in your image.)